# How to solve the given fourth order algebraic equation for $\beta$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms

Actually, I am working to find the exact solution of the non linear ordinary differential equation $f'''+ff''-f'^2=0,$ where the boundary conditions is $f(0)=s, f'(0)=-1+\gamma{f''(0)+\delta{f'''(0)}},f'(\infty)=0$. So, we assume the solution of the form $f(\eta)=A+Be^{-\beta\eta}$. The application of BC above give the value of A and B as $B={\frac{1}{\beta+\gamma\beta^2-\delta\beta^3}}$ and $A=s-{\frac{1}{\beta+\gamma\beta^2-\delta\beta^3}}$. Substituting the assume solution in the above differential we get $A=\beta$. Now using this relation inn the above to get the following fourth order algebraic equation $$\delta\beta^4-(\gamma+\delta{s})\beta^3+(\gamma{s}-1)\beta^2+s\beta-1=0.  ...........>(1)$$ Further, the required solution of the given problem in the following closed form which is read as $$f(\eta)=s-\frac{1}{\beta+\gamma\beta^2-\delta\beta^3}+\frac{1}{\beta+\gamma\beta^2-\delta\beta^3}e^{-\beta\eta}.$$  Please help me that how to find the equation (1) for $\beta$.

Comment: The command of Maple `dsolve({f(x)*diff(f(x), x, x, x) + f(x)*diff(f(x), x, x) - diff(f(x), x)^2 = 0, f(0) = s}, f(x))` performs $f\! \left(x\right)=s$.

Comment: When I give this command to Maple they cannot work may be the DE's is of third order then we needed to adjust all three conditions. Can you mention the full command for my mention problem.

Comment: According to this command, when I put the condition $f'(0)=-1+\gamma{f''(0)}+\delta{f'''(0)},f'(\infty)=0$ then its not working and the solution not be obtained like that as I wanted. Need your response and valuable feedback on my question.